# Overridng compareTo() method doesn't work as it supposed to

Tags: java, sorting

I have problem with sorting list of object depending on alphabetical order of `surname`:
I have class:

```
public class Osoba implements Comparable<Osoba>
{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String nip;
    private kraj country;

    public Osoba(String name, String surname, String nip, kraj country)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.nip = nip;
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Osoba o)
    {
        String tocompare = o.getsurname();
        if (this.surname.equalsIgnoreCase(tocompare))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.surname.compareTo(tocompare) == -1)
            {
                return -1;
            } else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       return this.nip +  " " +this.surname+ " " + this.name;
    }

    public String getsurname()
    {
        return surname;
    }

}
```

Then I have got list of randomly generated people. I invoke `Collection.sort(myList)` but it is not sorting my list. What am I doing wrong?
Example:

```
6438088470 Mcpherson Jemima
4728926902 Mcpherson Neville
8093413641 Ballard Neville
8485620409 Mcpherson Neville
6118892423 Ballard Fallon
3110453986 Ballard Sybill
3338278297 Mcpherson Sybill
2797735926 Mcpherson Todd
7473716746 Mcpherson Evelyn
9519145537 Mcpherson Ima
After sorting:
6438088470 Mcpherson Jemima
4728926902 Mcpherson Neville
8093413641 Ballard Neville
8485620409 Mcpherson Neville
6118892423 Ballard Fallon
3110453986 Ballard Sybill
3338278297 Mcpherson Sybill
2797735926 Mcpherson Todd
7473716746 Mcpherson Evelyn
9519145537 Mcpherson Ima
```

Comment: Show us the code where you're sorting the list.

Comment: from this all I can tell you is that `this.surname.compareTo(tocompare) == -1` VERY RARELY is true. You need strings that are only lexically dissimilar by one character value. 99% of the time you'll fall into the else case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation of `Comparable`, [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) returns:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So, if `a` is *less than* `b` (*occurs before*, in the natural order of sorting) , `a.compareTo(b)` returns a ***negative number***, but not necessarily `-1`

Change

```
if (this.surname.compareTo(tocompare) == -1)
```

to

```
if (this.surname.compareTo(tocompare) < 0)
```

and you should be good.

**Edit:**
***Note:***
A better and simpler way to write this code is

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Osoba o)
{
    return this.surname.compareToIgnoreCase(tocompare.getsurname()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.compareTo returns all whole int values above and below zero. Therefore your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Osoba o)
{
    if (!this.surname.equalsIgnoreCase(o.getSurname()))
    {
        return this.surname.compareToIngoreCase(o.getSurname());
    }
    else
    {
        return this.name.compareToIngoreCase(o.getName());
    }
}
```